# Insert URL inside Google Spreadsheet [escaping characters?]

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

OK, the big picture is to use all my API Steam results inside Google Spreadsheet so I can create a database of my games and profile.

*note: I don't want to share my private STEAMID for security reasons*

So far so good, using the command `=importXML(url, xpath_query, locale)`. I tried.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=XXXXXXXXXXX&format=xml", "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[2])"
```

in the end I also tried changing `, en_US)` and removing the`,`

*notice that my xml locale appears `ES` because it is in Spain.*

But I believe that's not the reason for the error rather escaping the characters `/` `?` `:` and any other if I didn't find it.

I tried to escape `?` with `~` but the failure persists.

Why am I using xpath? is because it's the only way I know for now. I'll try  python later or I could just import the .json inside the Spreadsheet but for now I need xpath.

*the url above with STEAMID provides me a resulting file in .json, .xml, or .vdf*

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. According to the IMPORTXML help article from the Google Docs editors help center, this function only have two arguments. What lead you to try the use of the third argument (locale)? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The formula you quote will give a parse error because `"`quotes`"` are missing around the second argument.

Comment: @doublenary thanks for the detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have to do critical thinking to find this and it may help others!

The problem was when I was trying to copy the full XPATH of that Steam API webpage by using Chrome Developer Tools (`F12`), however, since chrome only displays a `html` format with `<head>` and `<body>` then I remebered that xml files don't have `<head>` and `<body>`!

[image]

I save the file and the file was indeed `xml` without `<head>` and `<body>` as displayed above.

So, the problem was related to my `xpath_query`.

I replaced the old,

```
"//*[@id='collapsible1']/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/span[2]"
```

with

```
"response/players/player"
```

problem solved!